# How to return from a promise if Ajax is not required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am using jQuery promises to pre-fill the value of a `select` option. This works fine, but my question is about what to do when an Ajax call is not actually required, so the code does not return a promise.

The code below works fine if `this.orgId` is not undefined. But when it is not, I get an error:

```
getFormValues: function() {
    var _this = this;
    return _this.prefillOrgs()
                .then(function(orgId) {
                  _this.globalOptions.orgId = orgId;
                  return true;
                });
},

prefillOrgs: function() {
    if (typeof this.orgId !== 'undefined') {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  '/api/1.0/org_code?exact=true&q=' + this.orgId,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this
        });
    } else {
        // Doing this produces an error
        return [];
    }
}
```

The error returned:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.prefillOrgs(...).then is not a function
```

I guess this is because returning `[]` is not a promise and does not have a `.then()` method defined. However, I would like to return `[]` as my data payload in this case.

How can I get around this? I'd prefer not to make an unnecessary Ajax call if possible.

UPDATE: The other thing worth noting is that I need the `this` context inside whatever is returned.

Comment: take a look at [deffered](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$.when`

```
 return $.when([]);
```

It converts a value (or group of values, or a promise) to a promise.

In ES6 the responsibilities are seprate - converting a value or promise to a promise is done with `Promise.resolve`

Comment: awesome thanks, that returns `[]` nicely, but I've lost my `this` context - is there anyway to include context? checking docs but can't see how...

Comment: There is no direct way, and moreover in jQuery 3.0 the context argument breaks. I strongly recommend to pass the context as a part of the response or .bind on the receiving side

Answer (score 1):

If a function is sometimes asynchronous and can return promise than it makes sense to always return promise for consistency. jQuery has [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) that can create promises from values. So

```
return [];
```

will become

```
return $.when([]);
```